# How to copy a microsoft silverlight table from my browser?

Tags: silverlight, browser, silverlight-5.0

I browse a password protected internet page for my work. I need to copy a table from the page and paste it into Excel. The table is displayed using microsoft silverlight 5. I've tried all the simple ways of copying the data (ctrl-c, right clicking) without luck. Is there anyway for me to export the table to excel?

Comment: Have you allowed Silverlight to interact with your local computer's clipboard?

Comment: Yeah on the permissions tab it says the clipboard is allowed.